# How to create a line break in an HTML element using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I can't seem to format my tooltip into 4 separate lines. I have a p element and want to break it up. I have tried adding br and \n and they don't seem to help.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr('class', 'tooltip');

tooltip.append("p");
```

//Here I go through my data using selectAll and append circles. the '.on' attribute is when I hover over a circle I want to see the tooltip

```
.on("mousemove", function(d){

if (d.source == "target") {              
    tooltip.select("p").text(d.source);
} else {                       
    tooltip.select("p").text("Line 1: " + "this is line 1" + "\n" + "line 2: " + "this is line 2");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `.text()`, use `.html()`, that way you can use `<br>` like so:

```
tooltip.select("p").html("Line1: this is line 1 <br> line 2: this is line 2");
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
tooltip.select("p").html(function(){
    return "Line 1: this is line 1 <br> line 2: this is line 2"
});
```

As this is how I currently use `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105796/5768908):

You can use either `html()` or `text()` methods here. The difference between them is that `text()` uses [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), while `html()` uses [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

We can see this at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/9ffa69f363b5ee9af2171879d798091eab68def0/src/selection/text.js#L7) for `text()`:

```
this.textContent = value;
```

And this at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/9ffa69f363b5ee9af2171879d798091eab68def0/src/selection/html.js#L7) for `html()`:

```
this.innerHTML = value;
```

Therefore, each method has its particularities.

**Using html()**

As already explained, you can use `html()` with `<br>`:

```js
d3.select("p").html("Line 1: " + "this is line 1" + "<br>" + "line 2: " + "this is line 2");
```

```html
<p></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Using text()**

For using the `text()` method, just as in your code, you have to select an adequate value for [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), like `pre`:

```js
var p = d3.select("p");
p.text("Line 1: " + "this is line 1" + "\n" + "line 2: " + "this is line 2");
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```